# How can I use a method or Expression in a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

We converted a Stored Procedure to a Linq query in Entity Framework 6.

It had a sub-query with `not exists` which we translated into `Any()`.
Because it has quite some conditional operators, I want to extract one or methods.
I can do that for one check with an `Expression<Func<TableRecord , bool>>`  but I cannot extend that with an AND for example.

This is the (simplified) original SQL query:

```
SELECT
    main.Id,
    main.VersionNumber,
    main.ClosingVersion
FROM TableRecord main
WHERE
    and not main.status = 'in progress'
    and not exists(select sub.Id from TableRecord sub                
                    where 
                        (sub.tbrId = main.tbrId
                            and 
                                ( sub.VersionNumber > main.VersionNumber
                                or
                                (sub.VersionNumber = main.VersionNumber and 
                                    sub.ClosingVersion = 'z' and main.ClosingVersion is null)
                                )
                        )
                )
```

This is the EF Linq statement (where part):

```
TableRecord.Where(main => 
                !TableRecord.Any(sub =>
                    sub.tbrId == main.tbrId &&
                    (sub.VersionNumber > main.VersionNumber
                     ||
                     sub.VersionNumber == main.VersionNumber && 
                     sub.ClosingVersion == "z" && main.ClosingVersion == null)));
```

If I extract the whole sub-query with an Expression, that still leaves me with the same operators and an Exception: **System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'main' of type 'TableRecord ' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined** :

```
public void MainMethod()
{
   ...

    TableRecord.Where(main => 
                !TableRecord.Any(SubQueryExpression(main)));
}

private static Expression<Func<TableRecord , bool>> SubQueryExpression(TableRecord main)
{
    return sub =>
        sub.tbrId == main.tbrId &&
                    (sub.VersionNumber > main.VersionNumber
                     ||
                     sub.VersionNumber == main.VersionNumber && 
                     sub.ClosingVersion == "z" && main.ClosingVersion == null)));
}
```

Initially I was thinking of using local functions:

```
private static Expression<Func<TableRecord , bool>> SubQueryExpression(TableRecord main)
{
    return sub =>
        sub.tbrId == main.tbrId &&
                    (sub.VersionNumber > main.VersionNumber
                     ||
                     sub.VersionNumber == main.VersionNumber && 
                     VersionEqualAndClosing(sub));
    
    bool VersionEqualAndClosing(TabelregelVersie sub)
    {
        return sub.VersionNumber == main.VersionNumber && sub.ClosingVersion == "z" && main.ClosingVersion == null;
    }
}
```

Is there a way extract a method or an expression?
To make easier to read and keep Sonar happy.

Comment: Specification pattern could help you I think. It will allow you to decompose and reuse query/sub query but will also facilitate the concatenation when you will use it in the EF query : https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/specification-pattern-c-implementation/

Comment: The Specification pattern looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Install LINQKit and rewrite your methods:

```cs
[Expandable(nameof(SubQueryExpressionImpl))]
private static bool SubQueryExpression(TableRecord main, TableRecord sub)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static Expression<Func<TableRecord, TableRecord, bool>> SubQueryExpressionImpl()
{
    return (main, sub) =>
        sub.tbrId == main.tbrId &&
                    (sub.VersionNumber > main.VersionNumber
                     ||
                     sub.VersionNumber == main.VersionNumber && 
                     VersionEqualAndClosing(main, sub));
}   

[Expandable(nameof(VersionEqualAndClosingImpl))]
public static bool VersionEqualAndClosing(TabelregelVersie main, TabelregelVersie sub)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static Expresion<Func<TabelregelVersie, TabelregelVersie, bool>> VersionEqualAndClosingImpl()
{
    return (main, sub) => sub.VersionNumber == main.VersionNumber && sub.ClosingVersion == "z" && main.ClosingVersion == null;
}
```

Then you can use them in the following way:

```cs
public void MainMethod()
{
   ...

    TableRecord
        .AsExpandable()
        .Where(main => 
                !TableRecord.Any(sub => SubQueryExpression(main, sub)));
}
```

Comment: This is not completely clear to me. Especially the methods that have the `NotImplementedException`. At this moment I prefer to do it without a third party library.

Comment: Because from function needed only signature. Body will be populated from other function. In your variant `VersionEqualAndClosing` will be never expanded without third party library and EF core will not translate your expression.